# Native language to compile to LLVM with openGL binding support

Tags: haskell, opengl-es, go, llvm, emscripten

So I'm looking for a language for a special project.

I'm working on a project where we are about to design some rendering modules that initially will be running in the browser, but more interesting on the long run, on multiple platforms (Android, IOS, Linux, Windows, the whole lot).. A scenario of true cross platform.

To fulfill this we would like to take advantage of emscripten, llvm and a native compiling language. As the modules will be graphically challenging it is a requirement that the language has openGL-LLVM bindings so that the emscript can translate the implementation into webgl. I've attempted to illustrate our desire below.

```
Source
|---> Native binaries
|---> LLVM
      |---> Javascript (via EMSCRIPTEN)
```

So this brings us to the question. Which language supports this? Possible languages are, as I see it, C, C++, Go, Rust, and Haskell. We would though really like to avoid C and C++, despite them being the most realistic choices.

As far as I can see, all languages have LLVM bindings, but its more the matter of having reliable openGL-LLVM bindings available.